# Run multiple processes in parallel, continue each after each finishes

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm on Windows environment, and suppose I have two toy programs, called `2.bat` and `5.bat`, which look like `timeout 2` and `timeout 5`, respectively.

I want to set up a script that runs both `2.bat` and `5.bat` in parallel, and when `2.bat` finishes it is ran again and likewise for `5.bat`. I'm pretty bad at Python, but after a bit of searching I see that I can do:

```
from subprocess import Popen

commands = ["2.bat", "5.bat"]
while True:
    procs = [Popen(i) for i in commands]  
    for p in procs:
       p.wait()
```

This doesn't do what I want: it waits for *both* processes to finish, and then again executes both. What I want to do (in pseudocode) is as follows:

```
while True:
    in parallel, run 2.bat and 5.bat
    when 2.bat finishes, rerun 2.bat again
    when 5.bat finishes, rerun 5.bat again
```

Can I achieve this with `subprocess`, or do I need other libraries?

Comment: You can use built-in like `_thread` there is a simple function `start_new_thread()`: `from _thread import start_new_thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution would be:

```py
from _thread import start_new_thread
from subprocess import Popen


commands = ["2.bat", "5.bat"]


def run_bat(file):
    while True:
        p = Popen(file)
        p.wait()


for command in commands:
    start_new_thread(run_bat, (command, ))

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: @DanTony it is a bit weird but I updated my answer, apparently it is not possible to start a thread if the actual program doesn't run (I guess because it will finish and kill all associated threads)

Comment: @DanTony there is actually probably a bit better threading library `threading` just I know this one so that is what I used